# How to translate picklist values into german language

Tags: apex

I have a custom picklist in a visualforce page. The picklist values come from custom settings. In custom settings I have as : Name  & countryCode__c .
for ex: UnitedStates USA. The picklist bindings as as follows.

```
public List<selectOption> countriesList { 
    set; 
    get{

        List<selectOption> countriesList = new List<selectOption>();
        countriesList.add(new selectOption(' ','--Select--'));

        map<string,Countries__c> countryMap = Countries__c.getAll();
        List<string> countries = new List<string>();
        countries.addAll(countryMap.keySet());
        countries.sort();

        for(string country : countries){

            Countries__c c = countryMap.get(country);
            countriesList.add(new selectOption(c.CountryCode__c, c.Name));
        }

        return countriesList; 
    } 
}
```

Also there is some static text for which I will use custom Labels.
Please let me know how to tackle the language change for custom picklist values.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to just use a normal picklist?

Comment: @sfdcfox, I got ur point but the design is such that I cannot modify it. so I went with custom settings.

Comment: If you create a custom picklist field, you can then go to Setup > Translation Workbench > Translate, and translate the values into German. The values will automatically adapt based on the page's or user's language.

Comment: @sfdcfox, ur answer works if the picklist values are stored in the object.But its not the case in my scenario..

Comment: Maybe the design was made by someone who has no idea what Salesforce is and what features it has? Implementing picklists by using custom settings sounds like a strange idea.